# Combobox updating issue

Tags: c#

### UPDATED

I have an application that updates a combobox based on the values selected from another combobox.E.g List of states combobox will be populated based on the country selected from the "country" combobox.The datasource for the state combobox is a dataset based on a MySQL database. The issue is that if a country is selected first, the state combobox loads fine,but if i select another country,the state combobox is populated with:

```
  System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor
```

I researched and found out that the issue has to do with me being unable to update the datasource of the combobox,but i have to do this because the values are stored in different tables,and require different queries. So, how can i clear the datasource/resolve this issue?.

I have updated the post to add my code below(first is the code for the first combobox which populates the next based on values selected here:

```
  private void cboDisp1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cboProd1.Enabled = false;
        cboProd1.Invalidate();
        string dispensation1;
        dispensation1 = cboDisp1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (dispensation1 == "1")
        {

        }
        else
        { cboProd1.Enabled = true;
        LoadDispensationCode(dispensation1,"1");
         }
    }
```

This code shows part of the method that populates the second combobox:

```
 private void LoadDispensationCode(string text_id,string line_no)
    {
        string txt_id=text_id;
        string ln_no=line_no;
        //MessageBox.Show(txt_id, "Value");
        txt_id = text_id;
        if (txt_id == "1")
        { }
        if
            (txt_id == "2")
        { LoadConsultation("1","1"); }
        if(txt_id=="3")
        {
            LoadDrug(ln_no);
            }.......
```

This code shows the method that fills the dataset based on the query to the MySQL database, and loads the combobox.

```
      private void LoadDrug(string line_no)
    {  
        string ln_no;
        ln_no = line_no;
        //MessageBox.Show(ln_no,"value of text");
        if (ln_no =="1")
        {
         try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = HopeDB.GetConnection();
                String selectStatement = "Select id,code from drugs order by id";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds, "drugs");
                adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "drugs");

                   cboProd1.DisplayMember = "drugs.code";
                cboProd1.ValueMember = "drugs.id";
                cboProd1.DataSource = ds;
                connection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString()); }

        } 

    }
```

This code is another method that generates another dataset.

```
               private void LoadVaccine(string line_no)
    {

        string ln_no = line_no;
        if (ln_no == "1")
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = HopeDB.GetConnection();
                String selectStatement = "Select id,code from vaccines order by id";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds, "vaccines");
                adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "vaccines");

                cboProd1.DisplayMember = "vaccines.code";
                cboProd1.ValueMember = "vaccines.id";
                cboProd1.DataSource = ds;
                //cboStateIDFNo.Enabled =false;
                //cboVisitType.Enabled =false;
                //cboStatus.Enabled = false;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString()); }
        } 
    }
```

As mentioned earlier,i need help on updating the combobox  with fresh data from a different dataset when the first combobox is changed,and another method is called.

Comment: please give us your code segment if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can bind `ComboBox`s to a dataset, because you can't specify the DataMember. That being the case, you should instead set the ComboBox.DataSource to the datatable in question and then set the display/value members:

```
cboProd1.DataSource = ds.Tables["drugs"];
cboProd1.DisplayMember = "code";
cboProd1.ValueMember = "id";
```

Give that a try and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you are updating the combobox data source.

```
CountryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
{
    string[] states = GetStates(CountryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
    StateComboBox.DataSource = states;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid directly binding your combobox to the dataset here, and instead create a small extra layer of processing, just to keep your UI in check.

**Pseudo code below:**

So instead of

```
//bind directly to dataset/query
comboBox.DataSource = dsCountries;
```

something like

```
    public void Load()
    {
        //set up combobox, bind to countries
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.DataSource = GetCountries(ds);
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //when comboBox selection changed, load countries based on selected object
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, s) =>
        {
            var countrySelected = (Country)comboBox.SelectedItem;

            //populate countries based on selection
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build a list of countries, based upon the rows in a resulting dataset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="set"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Country> GetCountries(DataSet set)
    {
        List<Country> result = new List<Country>();

        foreach (DataRow row in set.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result.Add(new Country()
            {
                ID = (int)row.ItemArray[0],
                Name = (string)row.ItemArray[1]
            });
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: i will get my code and paste it in a bit...am away from my development machine right now.Thanks...